# Looking for a CSS optimizer (php script or online services)

Tags: php, css, optimization

I'm looking for a css optimizer. It should be a php script so I can install on my host or online services. I need some feature like below. Any recommended?

from:

```
margin-top:5px;
margin-right:10px;
margin-bottom:8px;
margin-left:2px;
```

to:

```
=> margin:5px 10px 8px 2px;
```

from:

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
```

to:

```
=> -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
=> -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: I doubt that any existing css optimizer will do that second one.

Comment: And I am wrong: http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/wiki/Configuration#convert-css3-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSSmin?](http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try cssmin extension: https://github.com/c9s/pecl-cssmin

Since it's a C extension, it's super fast than the pure PHP CSSMin implementation.